# TLS error will not let me access iLO

Tags: ssl, ilo, hpe

So I acquired a new DL380 Gen7 and am trying to access iLO.
I discovered that the iLO version is severely out of date.
It is *SO* out of date that no matter what I do, the webpage will not display and simply comes up with something about a TLS error:

[image: screenshot]

I know updating the iLO would help, but I cannot update, without accessing iLO, so I'm back where I started.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an older browser version to access it until you have iLO updated.

Most browsers are available as a portable version that doesn't even need to be installed.

Here are the latest version numbers for Firefox and Chrome that have the outdated SSL and TLS versions enabled (disabled):

|  | SSL2 | SSL3 | TLS1.0 | TLS1.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Firefox | 1.5 (7) | 33 (38) | 77 (107) | 77 (107) |
| Chrome | (9) | 39 (43) | 90 | 90 |

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_history_for_TLS/SSL_support_in_web_browsers)

Comment: Can you reccomend one? I've tried edge and chrome

Comment: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/ - find an sufficiently old release.

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic. It doesn't really matter which one as long as it supports your needed SSL/TLS version.

Comment: This worked. Thankyou so much.